# Where can I find the limiting distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance in R?

Tags: r, complexity-theory

While doing an experiment on importance sampling, I simulate values of Kolmogorov-Smirnov distances

D<sub>n</sub> = max<sub>x</sub> |F<sub>n</sub>(x)-F(x)|

where n is the size of the original importance sample and I want to compare those values to [the asymptotic distribution of the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45966/7224), or [Kolmogorov distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45966/7224), i.e.

Vn D<sub>n</sub>  --->  sup<sub>0<t<1</sub>|B(t)|

where B is the Brownian bridge.

Since `ks.test` relies on this asymptotic distribution, its cdf is already present somewhere in R and I would like to know how to access it. The R function `ks.test` contains the instruction

```
PVAL <- 1 - if (alternative == "two.sided") 
                .Call(C_pKolmogorov2x, STATISTIC, n)
```

but my own call to `C_pKolmogorov2x` does not work.

Comment: It seems to me that the function `pkolm` from the package [`kolmim`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kolmim/) provides a wrapper for `pKolmogorov2x`.

Comment: You're welcome. It seems strange that one can't call C-Functions directly. Just googled a little bit but found no solution as to how one could access `pKolmogorov2x` directly.

Comment: Strange indeed. If I redefine `pkolm` myself exactly as in the package, it does not recognize `pKolmogorov2x`...

Comment: Ok, got it! Try the following, for example: `.Call(stats:::C_pKolmogorov2x,  STATISTIC = 0.04, n = 200)`, this yields $0.1067137$ for me.

Comment: Subtle! Thanks for looking into this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relevant excerpt from the "Writing R extensions" [manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#useDynLib)

> Then, the directive in the NAMESPACE file
>
> useDynLib(myDLL, .registration = TRUE)
>
> causes the DLL to be loaded and also for the R variables foo, bar_sym,
>   R_call_sym and R_version_sym to be defined in the package’s namespace.

Translated to human speak this means (roughly) that the default place for all the non-R code is in the package namespace. Hence the need of triple colon.

So if you find in the code the `.Call(something,args)`, you can invoke it from the comandline by `.Call(package:::something,args)`. This is why simple call to `C_pKolmogorovx` did not work. The R was not finding it, since package namespace is intended for the package, not the user.

If you want to find out where the external code lies you need to look into 2 files. First NAMESPACE of the package to see whether the  `useDynLib` is used to register the external code functions, and then look into `src/init.c` file where all the available external code functions from the package are registered.